# Master-slave, are those can have different rosbags?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosbag, roscore, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI

We are currently dealing with remote communication control strategy and
I wonder Mater-Slave returns different rosbags if rosbag package running on different machines.
In fact, **we want to record the communication delay of our system due to wireless communication**.
I thought the rostime of the slave is associated with that of the Master correct?
If so, those two rosbags recorded by two machines will be exactly the same theoretically.
However, how is it in practice?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384659/master-slave,-are-those-can-have-different-rosbags?/) by [Kim_3957](https://answers.ros.org/users/76143/kim_3957/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2021-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are no masters or slaves in a ROS 1 system.

Communication is either publish-subscribe (ie: peer-to-peer), service-based (ie: client-server) or action-based (client-server).

The *only* "master" is the `roscore`, but that is not involved in communication between nodes and only serves as a DNS (ie: "which topic is published where?", etc). It does not participate in the exchange of bytes between nodes. ROS does not use a *broker*.

> I thought the rostime of the slave is associated with that of the Master correct?

No, that's not correct.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kim_3957](https://answers.ros.org/users/76143/kim_3957/) on 2021-08-19**:
Thanks for the answer. You saved my team. Thanks